# Considering - meaning in this sentence

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of considering in this sentence?

We're just fine, **considering**.

Comment: See meaning #2 at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/considering?s=t): "(adverb) 2. Informal. with all things considered (used only after the statement it modifies):
*He paints very well, considering.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is short for *considering the circumstances*.

It means "we are just fine, even though the circumstances in which we find ourselves make it hard to be really happy".

When someone answers this to a standard "how are you?", it may be awkward. But it is a normal answer when you ask someone how they are doing, and you *know* they are in a bad situation.

For instance, if my friend has recently lost a parent, I can ask him how he's doing now. He may answer "I'm fine, considering."
That means he is not really "fine", but given the fact that he is coping with his loss, he is doing reasonably well.

Answer (score 2):

"Considering" means: taking everything into account.

Here, when the speaker attaches "considering" after the sentence, it means that the speaker is taking into account all the factors that affect him in being "*just* fine".

Another example: He sings very well, considering. [Here considering tells us that we have taken into account the fact, say, not having a formal training in music]